# Difference between Django's ManyToManyField and ManyToManyRel

Tags: django, django-models, relationship

I'm new to `Django` and in my first project I'm working with models that are related to each other.

While typing the autocomplete function of `PyCharm` suggested me `ManyToManyField` and `ManyToManyRel`. However, I couldn't find an answer that describes the exact differences between those classes and when to use which one.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5216891/django-what-is-the-difference-rel-field

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please don´t use `ManyToManyRel` at a model. Django uses this kind of method for internal purpose.

If you create a model with a relationship, then use `ManyToManyField`. The `ManyToManyRel` is used for implementing the relationship at `ManyToManyField`